# Subversion + Apache 2.4 + Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, svn, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup subversion apache 2.4.7 authentication using active directory. where I am finding authzldapauthoritative is more supported in Apache 2.4.x. following are Apache configuration and please tell me the alternative syntax of authzldapauthoritative to configure it.

```
<Location /testing>

  # Uncomment this to enable the repository,
  DAV svn

  # Set this to the path to your repository
  SVNPath /subversion/testing

   AuthType basic
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.178.1/CN=MISC-User-IDs,DC=xtz,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
   AuthName "Testing Repository"
   AuthLDAPBindDN "userread@xcd.com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword Read#123
   Require ldap-group CN=subversiontesting,CN=MISC-Group-IDs,dc=xcd,dc=com


#  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
#    require valid-user
#  </LimitExcept>

</Location>
```